# How to click on a link with find_element_by_* through Selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriver

I need to click confirmation mail in my inbox. but it is not possible to click the link.

here is my html and tried code

```
<td bgcolor="#ffffff" style="padding:20px;">
<div style="color:rgb(0,0,0);font-size:16px;">
<strong>You are almost done!</strong><br><br>
    To complete Sunday Lankadeepa E-Paper registration, please click the link below:
</div>
<br><br>
<div style="width:616px;">
<a href="http://Sundaylankadeepa.newspaperdirect.com/epaper/confirmmail.aspx?code=ZUZ3S2K17GR&amp;rt=trial" rel="nofollow">

http://Sundaylankadeepa.newspaperdirect.com/epaper/confirmmail.aspx?code=ZUZ3K17GR&amp;rt=trial</a>
</div>
<br><br>
If clicking the link doesn't work, please select and copy the entire link. Then open a browser, paste the link in the address bar, and press Enter or Return on your keyboard.
```

Tried code...

```
text = "newspaperdirect"
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(text(),"%s")]' % text)
element.click()
```

Error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: 
{"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[contains(text(),"newspaperdirect")]"}
 (Session info: chrome=71.0.3578.98)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.45.615291 (ec3682e3c9061c10f26ea9e5cdcf3c53f3f74387),
platform=Windows NT 6.2.9200 x86_64)
```

Comment: Try to [wait for link](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#waits) and then click it

Comment: May be your xpath path is giving you list of web element. So use driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[contains(text(),"%s")]' % text) store this in weblist  and iterate over it

Answer (score 0):

Add some wait and use [find_element_by_partial_link_text](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Remote_RemoteWebDriver_FindElementByPartialLinkText.htm).

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/home/bitto/chromedriver')
url='file:///test.html' # url or .html file path here
text = "newspaperdirect"
browser.implicitly_wait(20) # seconds
browser.get(url)
browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text(text).click()
```

Comment: One should not use `sleep()` with selenium as @Anderson has already commented you should use `Waits` with `WebDriverWait` as shown here... https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#waits

Comment: @MosheSlavin Thanks for pointing this out! I will certainly take a look at this and update my answer.

Comment: @CoreyGoldberg Sorry for that. I was doing something else and then copy pasted this into my editor below. Edited it out.

Comment: implicit wait is only marginally better than time.sleep.  It's usually not what you would want to do.  Use WebdriverWait

Answer (score 0):

The text/word *newspaperdirect* is part of the `href` attribute of the `<a>` tag as well as part of the `innerHTML`

### Solution

To click on the element you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("newspaperdirect").click()
  ```
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div>a[rel='nofollow'][href*='newspaperdirect']").click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div/a[@rel='nofollow' and contains(@href, 'newspaperdirect')]").click()
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an explicit wait

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//a[contains(@rel,'nofollow') and contains(@href, 'newspaperdirect')]')))
```